# chrome issue on window.print()

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I have two pages. let's say **pageA.html** and **pageB.html**.

**pageA.html**

```
<a href="pageB.html" target="_blank"> preview </a>
```

So **pageB.html** will load in new tab(also CTRL + p).

**pageB.html**

```
<div onclick="window.print()"> print </div>
```

After clicking print, chrome will show print preview page.

Now if I don't cancel or save the print preview page, **pageA.html** will stuck (will be stuck on tinymce, bootstrap confirm box, and even page will not refresh). After cancelling or saving print preview page, **pageA.html** works as normal.
But by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on **pageB.html** will not give problem in **pageA.html**
So any hack or solution will be appreciable so that **pageA.html** will not stuck while leaving **pageB.html** unprinted.

Issue cannot be solve by even first loading **pageC.html** then again loading **pageB.html** through `window.location`.

Comment: In theory, page A and B are in separate process and everything happened in page B won't affect page A. What's your Chrome version?

Comment: My chrome version is 52.0.2743.116  on Ubuntu 12.04. version 56 on windows is also giving problem.